# XOR subset with minimum length of the subset

Tags: coding-theory

Array *a* has *n* integers.

Let *l* be the largest number in array *a*. Then, the expression for array *a*
is
∑<sup>n</sup><sub>i=0</sub>
d<sub>i</sub> ∗ 31<sup>i</sup>
mod
10
<sup>9</sup>
+ 7
.
Here, d<sub>i</sub>

is the size of largest
subset of array
a
whose XOR is equal to *i*.If there exist no
subset of array
*i*
then
d<sub>i</sub> = 0
a
whose XOR is i
then
d<sub>i</sub> = 0.

Major concern is how to calculate subset with particular XOR in fastest time.

Comment: As the number $10^9+7$ suggests, this is from an online coding competieion. - Which one?

Comment: Also, you might want to explain how to arrive at 3755653 from the sample input

Comment: yes it is.. some spoj question i am not able to find online description. also is the output of the expression written in line 2 of the question. Major concern is to get subset of the array with max length(number of terms) having the XOR of the terms in the subset equal to j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $d:=10$, all $a_i$ numbers are $<2^{d}$, hence so are all possible XOR results.
For $0\le i<2^{d}$ and $0\le j\le n$, let $f(i,j)$ denote the size of the largest subset of $\{a_1,\ldots, a_j\}$ that XORs to $i$. Then we have the recursion
$$f(i,j)=\max\{f(i,j-1),1+ f(i\operatorname{xor} a_j,j-1)\}$$
with the initial condition
$$ f(i,0)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }i=0\\-\infty&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
This allows us to compute $f(\cdot ,n)$ in $O(2^dn)$ steps. Here's some straightforward code to do so:

```
#define MODULUS 1000000007
#define PWR 1024  // 
#define NEGINFTY (-10001) // so that NEGINFTY+n < 0
int F[PWR];
unsigned n;
std::cin >> n;
for (int i=1; i<PWR; i++) F[i] = NEGINFTY;
F[0] = 0;
unsigned maxai = 0;
while (n-->0) {
  unsigned ai;
  std::cin >> ai;
  if (ai > maxai) maxai = ai;
  for (int i=0; i<PWR; i++) {
    unsigned ix = i ^ ai;
    if (i <= ix) {
      if (F[i] > F[ix])
        F[ix] = F[i]+1;
      else if (F[i] < F[ix])
        F[i] = F[ix]+1;
      else
        F[i] = ++F[ix];         
    }
  }
}
unsinged result = 0;
for (int i=maxi; i>=0; --i) {
  result = (result * 31) % MODULUS;
  if (F[i]>0) result = (result + F[i]) % MODULUS;
}
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Comment: @gauravarora 1024 instructions per input read are usually fast enough (and not much slower than the very input).  Since you are quite necessarily computing $\sim 2^d$ values $b_j$ and computing each of these needs to consider each of $n$ inputs, I doubt that it is possible to be faster than $O(2^dn)$